# Adding strings from multiple files into sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I hope you are doing very well. I am new in learning sqlite, I have three files in a folder, in which each file contain lines of strings (in Hexadecimal form), I am trying to add each line from file into one column in sqlite3 db, I have writted code, it cause errors

```html
import os
import sqlite3
path = r'H:\ttestt'
os.chdir(path)
def read_text_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        file = f.read()
        file = file.split("\n")
        conn = sqlite3.connect("checksum.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS checksum(first text)""")
        print(file_path)
        for i in file:
            print(i)
            c.execute(f"INSERT INTO checksum VALUES({i})")
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".java"):
        file_path = f"{path}\{file}"
        read_text_file(file_path)
```

Files are in this form:
[image: Files]

Is there something wrong with my code ? why is it generating errors, such as "0D" can not be added etc. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a table on each iteration you call read_text_file().

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html has this:

> It is usually an error to attempt to create a new table in a database that already contains a table, index or view of the same name. However, if the "IF NOT EXISTS" clause is specified as part of the CREATE TABLE statement and a table or view of the same name already exists, the CREATE TABLE command simply has no effect (and no error message is returned)

So, modify the line:

```py
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE checksum(first text)""")
```

```py
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS checksum(first text) """)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "G:\Feb_Research_Work\sqlite_prac.py", line 70, in read_text_file
    c.execute(f"INSERT INTO checksum VALUES({i})")
    sqlite3.OperationalError: near "14": syntax error

Comment: It is still showing syntax error

Comment: it shows syntax error because your insert is not written correctly. That is unrelated to the answer i posted. However, consider this, your "checksum" table has one field and its type is TEXT.   How would you denote that the value you are inserting is TEXT (string in python) ? Even in python code you just cant say `my_string_variable = this is a string value`  - you mark the value as string by adding quotes around the actual value ..